# Io-ts decoder error for intersection type

Tags: javascript, typescript, fp-ts

Currently I am working on a project which has an fp-ts and io-ts stack. I am trying to validate all the responses we get from backend with `io-ts`. I came to know `io-ts` doesn't have easy way to make `optional` type of `typescript`.
And from this **[issue](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/issues/56)** found a work around to make object with optional fields.

I want to create type which looks something like this.

```
type finalType = {
  req: string;
  opt?: string;
};
```

In our project, we have this `runDecoder` function which validates response data with `io-ts` types. It works perfectly fine with normal `io-ts` types which are not made optional.

But issue comes in validation when it tries to validate the type which was made optional with help of the `t.intersection` type. Here is the code with an example

```
import * as Either from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as io from "io-ts";

export const runDecoder = <T extends io.Props>(type: io.TypeC<T>) => (
  data: unknown
) => {
  const result = type.decode(data);
  if (Either.isLeft(result)) {
    return Error("error");
  }
  return result.right;
};

// I want to create type something like this
// type finalType = {
//   req: string;
//   opt?: string;
// };

const OptionType = io.partial({
  opt: io.string
});

const RequiredType = io.type({
  req: io.string
});

const FinalType = io.intersection([RequiredType, OptionType]);

type resultType = io.TypeOf<typeof FinalType>;

const respose:resultType = {
  req: "str"
};

const decoded = runDecoder(FinalType)(respose);
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Argument of type 'IntersectionC<[TypeC<{ req: StringC; }>, PartialC<{ opt: StringC; }>]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeC<Props>'.
  Property 'props' is missing in type 'IntersectionC<[TypeC<{ req: StringC; }>, PartialC<{ opt: StringC; }>]>' but required in type 'TypeC<Props>'.
```

I tried to understand the error but I am not able to figure it out whats wrong here with `runDecoder` method. Here is the **[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/io-ts-play-ground-v2g2p?file=/src/decoder.ts)** link.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `FinalType` is a `IntersectionType`, whereas `runDecoder` accepts a `TypeC`.

```
Type<A, O, I>
├ InterfaceType<P, A, O, I>     (+ readonly props: P)
│ └ TypeC<P extends Props>
└ IntersectionType<CS, A, O, I> (+ readonly types: CS)
```

I've haven't used io-ts yet, but to me it seems like the [`InterfaceType`](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/modules/index.ts.html#interfacetype-class) class (and therefore also the `TypeC` interface that extends it) is only for codecs for a simple object type (like `{req: string; opt?: string}`), not for intersection types (like `{req: string} & {opt?: string}`). Even though these types in TypeScript may be semantically equivalent, they are not represented the same way in io-ts.

The error you're getting is due to the `FinalType` not having the `props` property required in `InterfaceType` because `FinalType` is an `IntersectionType`.

I would make `runDecoder` accept simply a [`Type`](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/modules/index.ts.html#type-class) or even a [`Decoder`](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts/modules/index.ts.html#decoder-interface) (which `Type` extends):

```
// I: input type
// A: output type
export const runDecoder = <I, A>(type: io.Decoder<I, A>) => (
  data: I
): A | Error => {
  // ...
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/io-ts-play-ground-forked-v2hy8?file=/src/decoder.ts)

Comment: thank you so much for explaining the error and solution. That makes sense to me now!